# Using JQuery or Javascript, how can I tie a click function to control the scroll of an element/div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, scrollbar, mouse

Using JQuery or Javascript, how can I tie a click function to control the scroll of an element/div? I want to add buttons to control the vertical scroll of a div without changing positioning or margins? Thank You in advance!

Right now i have the scrollbars hidden and I can only scroll by using the mousewheel, I need to add another functionality in case the user is on mobile or doesn't have a scroll wheel on their mouse.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://www.infinite-scroll.com/

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".up-button").on('click', function () {
   $("#containing-div").animate({scrollTop: '-=20px'});
});
```

For `.down-button` you would use `+=20px`

http://jsfiddle.net/Yyw7Z/

Answer (score 0):

Look at the jQuery api, they have [`scrollTop()`](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/)